# Is it possible for gcc to read static library from pipe?

Tags: gcc

As a project requirement we are not allowed to put the existing static library to harddisk and link it with user's code. (yes, sounds strange)  I know that gcc can read from stdin the source code and compile it as long as you specified the language by "-x" option, but I didn't find any clue on how to read static library from stdin or pipe. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Well, where *is* the static library? :(

Comment: @pst: it's unpacked from somewhere, maybe a database file.

Comment: Is using a "virtual" or "temporary" filesystem an option?

Comment: @pst: I thought about it before, but not so strong as pipe. Set up a virtual fs, then call gcc, then clean the fs, all on-the-fly... Sounds this is the only way...

Comment: Can you explain why you aren't allowed to put the library on disk?  It sounds like a very weird restriction.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: to prevent the library from being arbitrarily used by user. Our tool wants to control the link between the user code and this library. I've been thinking about this all the night. I think the answer is simply NO. I may need to look for other approach...  Thanks, everyone.